# Get selected row and column AFTER editing JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener

I would like to perform an action after a table cell has been edited. However, after I used `tablechanged` and print the source cell, there was an error. Then I managed to find that the error was due to `e.source` not being an instance of a `table`but instead a `DefaultTableModel`.How do you get the selected row and column AFTER editing?

Here's a sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame main = new JFrame();

    JTable table = new JTable(6, 4);
    table.setSize(300, 300);

    table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            Object s = e.getSource();
            //JTable t = (JTable) s;
            //int x = t.getSelectedRow();
            //int y = t.getSelectedColumn();
            //System.out.println("Cell at " + x + "," + y);

            if (s instanceof JTable)
                System.out.println("TABLE");
            else
                System.out.println("Not a table");
        }
    });
    main.add(table);
    main.setSize(300,300);
    main.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    main.setVisible(true);
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((TableModel)e.getSource()).getValueAt` and rows between `e.getFirstRow/LastRow`.